# Creating model for JSON where key is a value

Tags: ios, json, swift, objectmapper

**JSON** :

```
{  
    "rows" :
    [
        {
            "_id": "5cdc0ede5c3dcb04bdb3a972",
            "emp_code": 187,
            "log_id": 361711,
            "punch_time": "2019-05-07T04:00:33.000Z",
            "pin_type": 1,
            "status": 4,
            "__v": 0
        },
        {
            "_id": "5cdc40de5c3dcb04bdb3a972",
            "emp_code": 111,
            "log_id": 361701,
            "punch_time": "2019-05-07T04:00:35.000Z",
            "pin_type": 101,
            "status": 4,
            "__v": 0
        }
    ],
    "pin_type_text": {
        "1": "In Fingerprint",
        "4": "In Card",
        "101": "Out Fingerprint",
        "104": "Out Card"
    }
}
```

The value of **pin_type** in each row refers to the record in **pin_type_text** mapped with it's key.

I am using **AlamofireObjectMapper** for creating models, and here is the PinTypeText model :

```
class PinTypeText : Mappable {

    var inFingerprint: String?
    var inCard: String?
    var outFingerprint: String?
    var outCard: String?

    required init?(map: Map) {

    }

    func mapping(map: Map) {
        self.inFingerprint <- map["1"]
        self.inCard <- map["4"]
        self.outFingerprint <- map["101"]
        self.outCard <- map["104"]
    }  
}
```

**Issue** : Suppose in future, the pin_type values - **1, 4, 101, 104** change in the backend, how can I handle such a case without changing my model. As per this model structure, I need to change my model class every time the backend model changes

Comment: You can use `Codable` containers for parsing that kind of data.

Comment: @PGDev : But for codable, won't I need to name the variable as the same in the JSON i.e. 1,4,101,104 ? Which isn't possible naming convention.

Comment: Since your JSON is updated due to version migration, you might want to create two models to handle different API response JSON, then your ObjectMapper is able to mapping for different version with no issues.  e.g. PinTypeText_V1, PinTypeText_V2 inherit from same parent model PinTypeText with different mapping using ObjectMapper

Comment: @PeterGuo : But that would require the code to be updated every time there is change in backend, won't it ?

Comment: @Nitish Added an answer with `codable`. Check it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you can use `Codable` as a solution,

**1.** Create a model `Row` that will contain the data of a single row in `rows` array of `json`, i.e.

```
class Row: Decodable {
    var id: String?
    var pinType: String?
    var pinId: Int?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id = "_id"
        case pinId = "pin_type"
    }
}
```

In the above model, I've used 2 different properties - `pinType and pinId`.

1. `pinId` will contain the `pin_type` value in the `row`
2. `pinType` will contain the actual value corresponding to `pinId`. We'll fill this value later.

Also, I've only used a small set of keys of the `row`. You can add more as required.

**2.** Next create another model `Response` that will contain an `array` of `Row`, i.e.

```
class Response: Decodable {
    var rows: [Row]?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case rows, pin_type_text
    }

    required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        rows = try values.decodeIfPresent([Row].self, forKey: .rows)
        let pinTypeText = try values.decodeIfPresent([String:String].self, forKey: .pin_type_text)
        rows?.forEach({ (row) in
            if let pinId = row.pinId {
                row.pinType = pinTypeText?[String(pinId)]
            }
        })
    }
}
```

In the above model,

1. `rows` array in `json` is parsed as `[Row]`.
2. `pinTypeText` `dictionary` is parsed as `[String:String]` type.
3. `[Row]` is enumerated to fill `pinType` in each `row` using `pinId` and `pinTypeText dictionary`.

When using, you need to use `pinType` property of a `Row` object.

```
response?.rows?.forEach({ print($0.pinType) }) //This line will print - "In Fingerprint" and "Out Fingerprint"
```

Let me know in case you face issue implementing this approach.